# java.awt.Rectangle#intersects(Rectangle r) ugly implementation?

Tags: java, swing, awt

The following is `intersects(Rectangle r)` method from awt [Rectangle](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/awt/Rectangle.java)
 source code.
I add some comments starting with `//*` related to my question:
Since the code verifies that rw (for example) is positive then rw `rw+rx` must be bigger than `rx`.
If that is the case `rw < rx` is always false, so why is it checked ?

```
/**
 * Determines whether or not this {@code Rectangle} and the specified
 * {@code Rectangle} intersect. Two rectangles intersect if
 * their intersection is nonempty.
 *
 * @param r the specified {@code Rectangle}
 * @return    {@code true} if the specified {@code Rectangle}
 *            and this {@code Rectangle} intersect;
 *            {@code false} otherwise.
 */
public boolean intersects(Rectangle r) {
    int tw = width;
    int th = height;
    int rw = r.width;
    int rh = r.height;
    if (rw <= 0 || rh <= 0 || tw <= 0 || th <= 0) return false;
    int tx = x;
    int ty = y;
    int rx = r.x;
    int ry = r.y;
    //*at this point rw must be positive
    rw += rx;    //*after this assignment rw must be bigger than rx
    rh += ry;
    tw += tx;
    th += ty;
    //      overflow || intersect
    return (rw < rx || rw > tx) &&  //*rw < rx should always be false
            (rh < ry || rh > ty) &&
            (tw < tx || tw > rx) &&
            (th < ty || th > ry);
}
```

The same applies to `rh < ry` and `tw < tx` and  `th < ty`.

Comment: Most probably, nobody cared enough to dive into that (ugly) piece of code. The implementation gives correct results, only might waste a few CPU cycles (not sure, maybe some optimizer detects the redundancy). And for a human, it's hard to find that redundancy because of the "clever" re-use of the variables `rw`, `rh`, `tw`, and `th`.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I agree that it is ugly and not readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for `rw < rx` , `rh < ry`, `tw < tx` and `th < ty` are redundant and can be eliminated:

```
public boolean intersects(Rectangle r) {

    int tw = width;
    int th = height;
    int rw = r.width;
    int rh = r.height;
    if (rw <= 0 || rh <= 0 || tw <= 0 || th <= 0)return false;

    rw += r.x;
    rh += r.y;
    tw += x;
    th += y;

    return  rw > x &&
            rh > y &&
            tw > r.x &&
            th > r.y;
}
```

After doing that we can take it one step further, make the code more readable and concise:

```
public boolean intersects(Rectangle other) {

      //to intersect both vertical and horizontal edges need to cross
      return
                //check if horizontal edge cross
                other.width + other.x > x &&   //other max x is bigger than min x and
                other.x < width + x   &&       //other min x is smaller than max x
                //check if vertical edge cross
                other.height+ other.y > y &&
                other.y <height + y ;
}
```